# System and Other Tab missing in Magento 1.9.2.0

Tags: system-configuration

Suddenly , when I logged in admin panel of magento.
All tabs including **dashboard , system are missing** in magento 1.9.2.0.
Only Sales, Catalog , Cutomers ,Promotions and CMS tab are visible.

I had not installed any extensions. And tried to clean cache manually also my complier is disabled.But Not able to see Tabs. I have not created any other user/role.

Please help me out.

Comment: There was a security patch included in the latest release which changes the default permission for admin users from allow to deny unless specified by a controller. It's worth first of all logging in as your admin user then checking your roles and the user you are trying to login as have permission to view the configuration

Comment: can you plz explain how can I check my role and its permission ? As I have access to only   Sales, Catalog , Cutomers ,Promotions and CMS tabs. I have tried from admin_role, admin_rule database.

Comment: Plz .. Help me out anybody.. I gonna frustrated. Spend whole day but couldn't find anything.